# Google Cloud Printers not showing up in Chrome Desktop

Tags: macos, google-chrome, printing, printer, google-cloud-print

If i go to google.com/cloudprint i can see all of the printers I have enabled cloud print on that are linked to my google account. I have 7 printers in total in my cloud print dashboard.

When im in Chrome Desktop Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) running on OSX 10.11.6, and go to `File > Print` a couple of my cloud printers are available, but not all of them.

Any ideas why this is, and how i can get them to show up in Chrome desktop ?

Answer (score 0):

If they only fail to show on this or any OSX install then I'd be inclined to say it has something to do with either 1) airprint being absent or 2) airprint being misconfigured